# save client page selected value in database

Tags: asp.net, client

Hi I got a different problem here

here i'm loading client page (ex: yahoo.com) in my page using iframesource as yahoo.com

Now i want to selecte some specific lines in yahoo.com and i want to store it in my database.

Can somebody help me to do this

Thank you,
Nagu

Answer (score 1):

You are better off using HttpWebRequest to open the Url, then parsing the Response and select the lines you want.